# @Transactional not working using spring mvc and hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-aop, spring-transactions

I have tried a lot but `@Transactional` is still  not working.
I have refereed a lot but i still  didn't find any proper answers

I want to insert the same record in two different tables with do everything or nothing principle.
Means that if problem occurs while inserting data in one table then it must rollback from the already inserted table. So data must be inserted or rollbacked in both tables for any problem.

Please anyone help me...

```
package com.cds.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes;

import com.cds.service.SaveEmployeeService;
import com.cds.vo.EmployeeVo;


@Controller
public class SpringHibernateController {

    @Autowired
    SaveEmployeeService saveEmployeeService;

    @RequestMapping("home")
    public String showHomePage(){
        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping("form")
    public String showFormPage(){
        return "form";
    }

    @RequestMapping("submit")
    public String saveEmployeeFromData(@ModelAttribute("employee") EmployeeVo employeeVo,RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes){
        try{    
            saveEmployeeService.saveEmployeeAndCustomer(employeeVo);
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("success","Saved In Both Tables Successfully");
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("unsuccess","Unable To Save In Both Tables.. Please Try Again");
        }
        return "redirect:form";
    }

}
```

This is my service class which contains method that will insert the same records in two tables using `@Transactional` but its not working

```
@Service
public class SaveEmployeeServiceImpl implements SaveEmployeeService{

    @Autowired
    SaveEmployeeDAO saveEmployeeDAO;

    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void saveEmployeeAndCustomer(EmployeeVo employeeVo){
        int saveEmployee = saveEmployee(employeeVo);
        int saveCustomer = saveCustomer(employeeVo);
        if(saveEmployee==1 && saveCustomer==1){
            System.out.println("saved In both table successfully");
        }else{
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }



    public int saveEmployee(EmployeeVo employeeVo) {
        Employee employee=null;
        try {
            employee=new Employee();
            employee.setName(employeeVo.getName());
            employee.setJobtitle(employeeVo.getJobtitle());
            employee.setSalary(Integer.parseInt(employeeVo.getSalary()));
            employee.setPassword(Integer.parseInt(employeeVo.getPassword()));
            employee.setPhoto(employeeVo.getPhoto().getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return saveEmployeeDAO.saveEmployee(employee);
    }

    public int saveCustomer(EmployeeVo employeeVo) {
        int a=10/0;
        Customer cutomer=null;
        try {
            cutomer=new Customer();
            cutomer.setName(employeeVo.getName());
            cutomer.setJobtitle(employeeVo.getJobtitle());
            cutomer.setSalary(Integer.parseInt(employeeVo.getSalary()));
            cutomer.setPassword(Integer.parseInt(employeeVo.getPassword()));
            cutomer.setPhoto(employeeVo.getPhoto().getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return saveEmployeeDAO.saveCustomer(cutomer);
    }
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>


</web-app>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

<!-- 
<context:component-scan base-package="com.cds">
        <context:exclude-filter type="regex" expression="com.cds.controller.*"/>
    </context:component-scan>
     -->
//I have tried with above scan also but still its not working

 <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"></property>
        <property name="user" value="root"></property>
        <property name="password" value="admin"></property>
         <property name="acquireIncrement" value="5" />
        <property name="initialPoolSize" value="20"></property>
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="1000"></property>
    </bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.cds.model</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
             </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

   <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true"/> 

    </beans>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">


<context:component-scan base-package="com.cds.controller"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven /> 

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix"> <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value></property>
        <property name="suffix"> <value>.jsp</value></property>
</bean>

  <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    </bean>

 </beans>
```

Comment: What means `is not working.`?

Comment: Your transactions are defined in the root context (`ContextLoaderLIstener`) but your beans live in the child context (`DispatcherServlet`) and as AOP only applies to beans in the same application context.

Comment: i have created an arithmetic exception while inserting into second table,so according to @Transactional it should not insert data into forst table but its inserting.Its is not rollbacking the whole insertion process

Comment: Try this : Move the codes from  `saveEmployee` and `saveCustomer` to `saveEmployeeAndCustomer` and comment the result. May be it has something to do with `proxy` objects

Comment: as  int a=10/0; is unchked exception and I have used same thing  to check whether Transaction will work or not but in Spring JDBC and JDBC TX Manager  its working fine but while using spring-Hibernate and Tx Manager it is not rollbacking the transaction .I have tried with rollbackFor=Exception.class but still dint rolled back

Comment: spring @Transactional  make commit after method return in saveEmployeeAndCustomer .all insert execute after return and exception that relate to database dose not catch in this method .you will catch in ControllerAdvice or in controller